# Vue.js live search with more than 1 parameter

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How do I create a live search with `vue` and the parameters are 3 in the API, ie select 1, select 2 and textbox 1?

for example http://example.com/api/?param1=x&param2=xx&param3=xxx

[image]

Comment: This is far too broad a question to be answerable. Make an attempt and post a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: @DanielBeck I've edited it. Is it now more specific for you?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an endpoint in laravel for your search with your 3 parameters as get request as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

Secondly you need to write your Vue component and call that endpoint with an asynchronous request. The easiest way would probably be to use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios).

Register a click listener on your send button and make sure to prevent the default event so that it doesn't refresh your page. Get all the parameters out of your form and send a request like so:

```
  axios.get('/search?ID=12345&name=jondoe')
  .then(function (response) {
    // update your view here with the response. Example:
    this.resultTable = response.results
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution, Beside Vue I am also using axios for API requests and loadash for getting extra functionality vanilla js doesn't provide natively. If you are using Laravel Mix then you already have all these else import these using CDN

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In View Page

```
<select v-model="select1" >
        <option >1</option>
        <option >2</option>
 </select>
 <select v-model="select2" >
        <option >1</option>
        <option >2</option>
 </select>
<input type="text" v-model="textbox">
```

Now the main script part

```
<script>
  var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    select1: '',
    select2: '',
    textbox: '',
  },
  watch: {
    textbox: function() {
      if (this.textbox.length >= 3) { 
        this.findResults();
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    findResults: _.debounce(function() {
      self = this;
      axios.post('your laravel post url',{
                select1 : self.select1,
                select2 : self.select2,
                textbox : self.textbox,
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }, 500)
  }
})
</script>
```

I am not including the server side part all you need to do is just return your query object without converting into JSON.

Note I used watch to prevent calling the findResult function before user types at least some letters.

The loadash debounce function is used to delay the API request for 500 seconds for preventing frequent requesting.

I assume you know how to output return query object using v-for directive. If you don't know that comment below.